# Trying to override xml file of stripe

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I am trying to override xml of stripe to show Edittext inside framelayout horizontally

Here is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <com.stripe.android.view.CardBrandView
        android:id="@+id/card_brand_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/card_brand_view_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/card_brand_view_height"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/stripe_card_icon_padding"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/stripe_card_icon_padding"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/stripe_card_icon_padding"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        >

        <!-- The accessibilityTraversalBefore attribute is ignored in sdk < 22 -->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/card_number_text_input_layout"
            android:labelFor="@id/card_number_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"
            android:accessibilityTraversalBefore="@+id/text_input_expiry_date"
            android:nextFocusRight="@+id/text_input_expiry_date"
            android:nextFocusForward="@+id/text_input_expiry_date"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/text_input_expiry_date"
            android:contentDescription="@string/acc_label_card_number"
            android:accessibilityLiveRegion="polite"
            app:hintEnabled="false"
            style="@style/Stripe.CardInputWidget.TextInputLayout">
            <com.stripe.android.view.CardNumberEditText
                android:id="@+id/card_number_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:hint="@string/card_number_hint"
                style="@style/Stripe.CardInputWidget.EditText"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/expiry_date_text_input_layout"
            android:labelFor="@id/expiry_date_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/stripe_card_expiry_initial_margin"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"
            android:accessibilityTraversalBefore="@+id/text_input_cvc"
            android:accessibilityTraversalAfter="@+id/text_input_card_number"
            android:nextFocusRight="@+id/text_input_cvc"
            android:nextFocusForward="@+id/text_input_cvc"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/text_input_cvc"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@id/text_input_card_number"
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/text_input_card_number"
            android:contentDescription="@string/acc_label_expiry_date"
            android:accessibilityLiveRegion="polite"
            app:hintEnabled="false"
            style="@style/Stripe.CardInputWidget.TextInputLayout">
            <com.stripe.android.view.ExpiryDateEditText
                android:id="@+id/expiry_date_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:digits="@string/stripe_expiration_date_allowlist"
                android:hint="@string/expiry_date_hint"
                style="@style/Stripe.CardInputWidget.EditText"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/cvc_text_input_layout"
            android:labelFor="@id/cvc_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/stripe_card_cvc_initial_margin"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"
            android:accessibilityTraversalAfter="@+id/text_input_expiry_date"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@id/text_input_expiry_date"
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/text_input_expiry_date"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cvc_number_hint"
            android:accessibilityLiveRegion="polite"
            app:hintEnabled="false"
            style="@style/Stripe.CardInputWidget.TextInputLayout">
            <com.stripe.android.view.CvcEditText
                android:id="@+id/cvc_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                style="@style/Stripe.CardInputWidget.EditText"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/postal_code_text_input_layout"
            android:labelFor="@id/postal_code_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/stripe_card_cvc_initial_margin"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"
            android:accessibilityTraversalAfter="@+id/text_input_cvc"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@id/text_input_cvc"
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/text_input_cvc"
            android:contentDescription="@string/address_label_postal_code"
            android:accessibilityLiveRegion="polite"
            app:hintEnabled="false"
            style="@style/Stripe.CardInputWidget.TextInputLayout">
            <com.stripe.android.view.PostalCodeEditText
                android:id="@+id/postal_code_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:enabled="false"
                style="@style/Stripe.CardInputWidget.EditText"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
</merge>
```

Here is the code I have used from stripe library and I am trying to override this, my requirement is to show all editText fields as horizontally with **match_parent** and show edittext horizontally into 4 rows

1. Card Number
2. CVC
3. Date Expiry
4. Postal Code

Thanks
Regards

Comment: I think if you want to achieve the stack effect, you'd better use LinearLayout or RelativeLayout than FrameLayout. Or you can experiement with android:layout_gravity for the frame layout and see if it fits your need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CardMultiLineWidget resolves my problem

https://stripe.dev/stripe-android/com/stripe/android/view/CardMultilineWidget.html